# IRA contribution income limits different than deduction income limit?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, income, self-directed-ira

I never had to consider it, but am I correct in noticing that the income limits Traditional IRA contribution are different than the income limits for actually taking the tax deduction?

The conundrum to me is that traditional IRA is supposed to be pretax, but if I have to coordinate the transfer myself (with the remainder of withheld employment income) because my employer has no facility to make the tax exempt deduction per paycheck, then I need to take a tax deduction during tax time.

Can I be under the income limit for contributions, but over the income limit for taking the tax deduction?

Let me know if I am misunderstanding this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no income limit for making Traditional IRA contributions. There are only income limits for the tax deductibility of such a contribution, given by the IRS [here](https://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/IRA-Deduction-Limits). If you above that income limit, then you are almost certainly better off doing a Roth IRA contribution except in special cases.

Traditional IRA contributions that are deductible are similar to 401(k) contributions, but not associated with your employer. You make the contribution on your own through a financial institution you choose. The deductibility benefit comes in when you file your tax return, and your IRA contribution will lower the amount of tax you owe (assuming you are eligible). You may want to decrease your tax withholding with your employer so you don't end up with a large refund because of this.

Comment: Keep in mind there are income limits to ROTH contributions.  Marrying filing jointly, with an AGI above 193K cannot contribute to a ROTH.  Back door ROTH contributions may be an option, but not for everyone.

Comment: If I was covered by a retirement plan at work for the year I am filing for, then I can't take a deduction if my modified AGI was more than $71,000? Thats what it says verbatim, just never considered it!

Comment: If I'm reading the IRS site correctly, you can contribute to a traditional IRA even if you exceed the income limit, but it's just not tax deductible?

Comment: @JeffMergler Yes. However, in most cases it is not a good idea to contribute to a traditional IRA if you're over the deductibility limit (unless you're planning to convert the money to a Roth IRA soon afterwards).

Comment: @CraigW, right, that's a "backdoor Roth" I believe. So, although legal to do so, its probably wiser financially speaking to just take the contribution you normally would have made and instead invest that into something sensible and in line with one's own risk and reward goals?

Comment: @JeffMergler Congress has "blessed" the backdoor Roth ([source](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ashleaebeling/2018/01/22/congress-blesses-roth-iras-for-everyone-even-the-well-paid/)) so no reason to avoid it as long as you have no other pre-tax IRA money.